# $A, B, C, D$ are sets such that $A ∪ B = C ∪ D$, and both $A ∩ B$ and $C ∩ D$ are empty

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A, B, C, D$ are sets such that $A ∪ B = C ∪ D$, and both $A ∩ B$ and $C ∩ D$ are empty.

Show that if $C ⊆ A$, then $B ⊆ D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in B$. Then $x \notin A$ and therefore $x \notin C$ (since $C \subseteq A$).

From this and from  $A \cup B = C \cup D$, we have $x \in D$